# TradingView PineScript: date associated with a request.earnings(syminfo.tickerid, earnings.actual) call

Tags: tradingview-api

this is a request related to TradingView PineScript

In using the request.earnings(syminfo.tickerid, earnings.actual) function, how can determine if the current bars DATE  has passed the next earning report ?

(I have tried to simulate by using a change in it's value, but sometimes "reported earnings" stay unchanged from qtr to qtr)

Thanks in advance

/Claus

(I have tried to simulate by using a change in it's value, but sometimes "reported earnings" stay unchanged from qtr to qtr) - I would like to have a function which eg returns the date of the request.earnings(syminfo.tickerid, earnings.actual) call

Comment: Do you found how to do this?